# Compiler error: memset was not declared in this scope

Tags: c++, gcc

I am trying to compile my C program in Ubuntu 9.10 (gcc 4.4.1).

I am getting this error:

```
Rect.cpp:344: error: ‘memset’ was not declared in this scope
```

But the problem is I have already included in my cpp file:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
```

And the same program compiles fine under Ubuntu 8.04 (gcc 4.2.4).

Please tell me what am I missing.

Comment: Something I still don't understand is why it compiles fine on older versions of gcc & ubuntu and not on newer versions. Can anyone explain why?

Comment: @Dennis: probably because the necessary header `<string.h>` is being `#include`d indirectly via some other `#include`d header in your older gcc/Ubuntu configuration.

Comment: @Dennis Adding -fpermissive to the gcc options might also help in those weird cases, although it is just a workaround

Answer (score 199, accepted):

You should include `<string.h>` (or its C++ equivalent, `<cstring>`).

Answer (score 145):

Whevever you get a problem like this just go to the [man page for the function](http://linux.die.net/man/3/memset) in question and it will tell you what header you are missing, e.g.

```
$ man memset

MEMSET(3)                BSD Library Functions Manual                MEMSET(3)

NAME
     memset -- fill a byte string with a byte value

LIBRARY
     Standard C Library (libc, -lc)

SYNOPSIS
     #include <string.h>

     void *
     memset(void *b, int c, size_t len);
```

Note that for C++ it's generally preferable to use the proper equivalent C++ headers, `<cstring>`/`<cstdio>`/`<cstdlib>`/etc, rather than C's `<string.h>`/`<stdio.h>`/`<stdlib.h>`/etc.