# implicit declaration of function ‘memset’ [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]

Tags: c

I have the following c code:

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    char buff[10];
    memset(buff,0,sizeof(buff));

    gets(buff);

    printf("\n The buffer entered is [%s]\n",buff);

    return 0;
}
```

When I run the code, I get the following warning:

```
warning: implicit declaration of function ‘memset’ [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
```

How should I solve the problem?

Thanks

Comment: `memset` is declared in `string.h`

Comment: Please please please don't use `gets`...

Comment: @Michael : $   man memset

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Add

```
#include <string.h>
```

at the top of file.

This because is the header file where the [memset](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/c_standard_library/c_function_memset.htm) prototype can be found by compiler.

Avoid using gets function... Use [scanf](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/c_standard_library/c_function_scanf.htm) or [fgets](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/c_standard_library/c_function_fgets.htm) instead.

Take a look [HERE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1694036/why-is-the-gets-function-so-dangerous-that-it-should-not-be-used)

Comment: now I have this error: warning: implicit declaration of function ‘gets’ [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
     gets(buff);

Comment: @Michael: see [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2506036/253056) to learn how to resolve these kinds of issues quickly and easily.

Comment: @Michael Did you remove stdio include? BTW avoid to use that function... Use [scanf](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/c_standard_library/c_function_scanf.htm) or [fgets](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/c_standard_library/c_function_fgets.htm) instead. Take a look [HERE](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1694036/why-is-the-gets-function-so-dangerous-that-it-should-not-be-used)

Answer (score 2):

Add

```
#include <string.h>
```

memset is available in string.h

Comment: now I have this error: warning: implicit declaration of function ‘gets’ [-Wimplicit-function-declaration] gets(buff);